# Fourier Series of a triangle wave.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

[image: An attempt to solve for X(n) on a white board]

- Hello everyone,
- I have a picture attached along with this question, please have a look at it.
- In this task I am asked to show how I should arrive at the result which is seen
  in bottom left corner of the white board.
- I would really appreciate if someone could let me know if there are any mistakes and if possible simplify my answer further to show what happens when different even/odd n numbers are plugged in.
- Thank you!

[This is the original question!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHQf8.jpg)

Comment: Pictures are not well understood by search engines, and people don't like clicking through links to get to the content of your question.   If you format your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), you are much more likely to get useful responses.

Comment: Nice whiteboard. Which is the actual question? I know the fourier series of a triangle signal, but how it is defined? I dont follow the whiteboard. Can you clarify the actual question?

Comment: Thank you for replying back! There is an original question at the bottom, you have to click into it (sorry not exactly familiar with text editing tools yet). I have to evaluate integral of piecewise triangular wave and get an answer for x(n) for which if n value is even it should evaluate to zero and if odd (see attached picture).